# Questions about SAML, OAuth

Tags: authentication, oauth, authorization, saml

I am working on a project to implement token based authentication in a system. I was thinking about using either SAML or OAuth.

I wanted to know if it is possible to represent the actual policies (which are ACL based for the system) inside the token. With the current design, I was thinking about giving the user a token which would contain all the resources and the permitted roles. The service, upon the request of the user, which check this token to see if the user has the required permission on the resources involved.

Is it possible to be represented using either SAML/OAuth tokens? If it is possible in both, which one should be used here. From most of the examples I saw, SAML is used for SSO solutions and OAuth is used for defining actual authorization policies. But it was not clear from the demos/examples if it is possible to give restrictive access on a particular resource using OAuth.

e.g. when a Facebook app wants to access your photos using OAuth, is it possible to restrict the access to only a particular album? Or is it more like all or nothing approach. Are there any resources which I can read to get more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most architectures (for both SAML and OAuth) use tokens that contain attributes upon which the relying party (or receiving API) then interprets and applies its own policy (ACL) upon.

In the case of OAuth, scopes are used to designate what permissions the Access Token represents.  Scopes can be as fine grained as you like (to cover cases like single photo album restriction).  These may have been authorized by the user in certain OAuth flows.  The token itself is not defined in the OAuth 2.0 spec - but you could make the format self-contained (perhaps digitally signed by the token issuer) so the scopes are held within it.  Some models use opaque tokens that need to be validated via callback (maybe back channel) to the issuer, then the scopes are returned to the relying party.

In SAML, an Attribute Statement can be present within a Assertion for a similar purpose.  The relying party interprets individual attributes to determine what the user is authorized to do.  The Attribute Statement may come through as part of SSO or it might be obtained via AttributeQuery at some later point (after authentication).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! In case of the said project, I think there would be 1000s of resources. So from my understanding of the roles, I would need to define thousands of roles? In case when one user is allowed to access multiple resources, a new role has to be designed.

But in case of SAML, this can be achieved using the AttributeQuery in the form of some XML statements and it would much cleaner?

Comment: It many ways it's about the same.  If you really need to control fine grained access then you could end up having a 1 to 1 mapping of roles/scopes to your resources.  You may also want to consider SAML AuthzDecisionQuery's which may alleviate you from defining roles (at least as they would be known between Identity Provider and Relying Party). Instead the RP simply asks the IdP if the user can access something (say a given URL).

Comment: I was under the impression that, in SAML, a user can get a token which would contain XML statements. I was planning to use these XML statements to define the resources the user in question can use along with the permissions allowed. With this implementation, there would be no need of defining any roles. The groups would still need to be defined, but it would just a natural extension of the ACLs which are already in place. That's why I think this would be a simpler and cleaner implementation than OAuth. Please correct me if my understanding is incorrect. Thanks again!

Comment: Sounds fine.  I was just suggesting "roles" because they are commonly used to abstract away the resource/permission definitions that you'd need to share between parties (probably it's the same as what you are doing with 'groups').  Gives you the flexibility to change one side without necessarily impacting the other.  You could do this with 'scopes' in OAuth as well in about the same fashion.  At least with OAuth you for sure get away with the complexities of dealing with XML which is a big plus.